# 'Series' object has no attribute 'resize'/"split"

Tags: python, caption

I was working on a project on image captioning.

The first function that we need to create is EncodeImage(). we need to preprocess the image in some ways and return the output. The function goes like this.

I am working on the Flicker8k dateset.It has 40455 images with 2 cols namely - Image and Captions.
1.
`

```
import tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image as tf_image
def encodeImage(img):
  img=img.resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
  x=tf_image.img_to_array(img)
  x=np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)
  x=preprocess_input(x)
  x=encode_model.predict(x)
  x=np.reshape(x,OUTPUT_DIM)
  return x
```

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
  image_path="/content/images"+data["image"][i]
  try:
    img=tf_image.load_img(image_path,target_size=(HEIGHT,WIDTH))
    
    encoded_images[data["image"][i].split(".")]=encodeImage(data["image"])
  except:
      print(i)
      remove_these.append(data["image"][i])
```

`
The second part has a try and except block. It is excluding the images that are non-supportive and putting them into remove_these. Now all my images are being transferred to remove_these.If I try to find the length of remove_these  and length of encoded Images by running the code- len(remove_these),len(encoded_images), it will give me - (40455, 0) Am I doing something wrong? Where is the issue?

To check myself I wrote seperate code:

```
a[a]=data["image"][i].split(".")
en=encodeImage(data["image"])
```

The first code produced the error - 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'. the second code produced an error - " 'Series' object has no attribute 'resize'.

Please help..

Comment: `data["image"]` is a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object. You call it like `data["image"].resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT))`, but 'Series' object has no attribute 'resize'.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. How do I run this code without the errors..

Comment: What's your desired type of `img` in `img=img.resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT))`?

Comment: WIDTH=299, HEIGHT=299.Image type here is .jpg

Comment: [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/img_to_array) takes `PIL.image` as input type. You need to convert the type of `data["image"]` to that.

Comment: You are right.  x=tf_image.img_to_array(img) - already converted the image to array in the first part of the code.